# Long file path get out of right margin on PDF

Tags: lyx, hyphenation

A simple LyX document consisting of one long file path, is wrapped inside the LyX GUI to the next line; but when exported to PDF it 'continues' after the right margin end.

I'd expect it to be automatically wrapped on the slashes.
How can I define some rule to do this?

This is the file path:

```
/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm
```

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the [url](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package -- I suggest you set the options `spaces`, `obeyspaces`, and `hyphens` when loading the package -- and use that package's `\path` macro to typeset the long path name.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\path{/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/dddd/eeee/ffff/gggg/hhhh/iiii/jjjj/kkkk/llll/mmmm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working. Sorry I can't upvote. However, something still bother me. I'm new to LyX and LaTex, and I can't comprehend how is it possible that by default 'strange words' that can't be hyphenated just disappear after the right margin. Shouldn't it be vice-verse? By default it should wrap (even on some arbitrary point, if it doesn't know the 'logical' place).

Comment: @Zvika - For TeX to create line breaks, it needs "rules" that determine where line breaks are permissible. An obvious candidate for a break point is an interword space. Hyphenation points, determined by whatever language-specific hyphenation rules may in force, are also permissible breakpoints (although associated with a penalty, so that TeX will try whenever possible to break lines at interword spaces). If TeX encounters a long "word" for which it cannot find hyphenation points, all it can do is to let the "word" protrude into the margin.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'd still have to get used to it, though...

Comment: @Zvika -- Don't worry, you'll get used to it soon.

Comment: Adding information for future LyX users who might encounter this:
A. If `PDF Properties` has `Use Heperref Support` it would clash with the paramters of `url` package. Disable it from LyX menu, and enable it from `LaTeX Preamble`, after loading `Url`.
B. If the path has `_`s, they should be inside an `ERT`